# Print next array keys in array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays that contain array key with the value, here the example :

```
Array  ( 
[0] => Array ( [Hotel] => N [Jayakarta] => NE [Jaya] => NE [sangat] => ADV [nyaman] => ADJ [ditempati] => V. )  
[1] => Array ( [Andi] => NOB [Hotel] => N [menginap] => V [disana] => N [selama] => N [satu] => NUM [minggu] => N. ) 
)
```

I want to make an output if I found a key of "Hotel" then I will print next key from "Hotel". For example :

`Hotel Jayakarta Jaya`

`Hotel menginap disana`

Here's what I am doing for the moment:

```
foreach($token2 as $index => $tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => $tokvalue) {
        if ($tokkey == "Hotel" and $tokvalue == "N"){
            echo $tokkey . " " ;

            while($cek == true && $x <= 2){
                $next = next($tok);
                echo key($tok). " " ;    

                $x++; 
            }
            echo ", ";
            $x = 1;
        }
    }   
}
```

And the output :

`Hotel Jayakarta jaya sangat , Hotel Hotel menginap`

The Expected Output should be as below:

`Hotel Jayakarta jaya sangat , Hotel menginap disana selama`

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: You haven't describe what it is you're trying to accomplish. What determines rather you keep and index?  Do you want all indexes after hotel? What determines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like following:

```
$i = 3;
foreach($token2 as $index => $tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => $tokvalue) {
        if ($tokkey == "Hotel" && $tokvalue == "N"){
            echo $tokkey . " " ;
            $i = 1;
        }
        else if($i < 3){
            echo $tokkey . " ";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this ?

```
$arrayOfHotels = array(0 => array('Hotel' => 'N' , 'Jakarta' => 'NE', 'Jaya' => 'NE', 'sangat' => 'ADV', 'nyaman' => 'ADJ', 'ditempati' => 'V.'),1 => array('Andi' => 'NOB', 'Hotel' => 'N', 'menginap' => 'V', 'disana' => 'N', 'selama' => 'N', 'satu' => 'NUM', 'minggu' => 'N.'));

echo '<pre>';
print_r(findHotel($arrayOfHotels));
echo '</pre>';

function findHotel($hotels)
{
    $isHotelFind = false;
    $isFirstThrough = true;
    foreach($hotels as $row => $value)
    {
        foreach ($value as $row2 => $value2)
        {
            if($row2 == "Hotel" && $value = 'N' && !$isHotelFind)
            {
                if($isFirstThrough)
                {
                    echo $row2 . " ";

                }
                else
                {
                    echo ", " . $row2 . " ";
                }
                $isHotelFind = true;
                $isFirstThrough = false;
            }
            if($isHotelFind && $row2 != "Hotel")
            {
                echo $row2 . " ";
            }
        }
        $isHotelFind = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search to find your key and remove leading elements before it.

```
$array = [
    [
     "Hotel"     => 'N',
     "Jayakarta" => 'NE',
     'Jaya'      => 'NE',
     'sangat'    => 'ADV',
     'nyaman'    => 'ADJ',
     'ditempati' => 'V.'
    ]
    ,
    [
     "Andi"     => 'NOB',
     "Hotel"    => 'N',
     'menginap' => 'V',
     'disana'   => 'N',
     'selama'   => 'N',
     'satu'     => 'NUM',
     'minggu'   => 'N.'
    ]
];


foreach ($array as $data) {
    // Find index to start
    $index = array_search("Hotel", array_keys($data));
    // Remove other keys
    $new_array_starting_hotel = array_splice($data, $index, count($data));
    // merge results
    $merged[] = implode(' ', array_keys($new_array_starting_hotel));
}

print_r($merged);
```

And output will be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hotel Jayakarta Jaya sangat nyaman ditempati
    [1] => Hotel menginap disana selama satu minggu
)
```

You can merge or implode all however you like.

Comment: Your output doesn't look like the intended output.